# Kusto query - how to get beginning datetime of current month

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Learning Kusto query and looking for a way to get beginning of current month datetime.
As of time I post this it is 2/25/2020 so output should looks like below represents Feb 1, 2020

[image]

This is what I have so far and works, but there should be better way of doing this.
Can anyone please let me know if this query can be improved?
What's the common practice of getting beginning of current month?

Below, get year and month, add leading 0 if needed for month then concatenate the string and assign to variable "d" which then look like "2020-02-01" and pass that string to todatetime()

```
let year = datetime_part("Year",now());
let month = datetime_part("Month",now());
let m = case(month < 10, strcat("0", month), tostring(month));
let d = strcat(year, "-", m, "-01" );
print todatetime(d);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the `startofmonth()` function.

Example:

```
MyKustoTable 
| project MonthStart = startofmonth(datetime('2020-2-5'))
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/startofmonthfunction

Comment: i used the function for other query but it just returns int of current month, which is '2' but am looking for a way to get datetime

Answer (score 1):

there's a `startofmonth()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/startofmonthfunction